# Play ogg stream with android MediaPlayer

Tags: android, stream, media-player, ogg

My app plays an OGG stream via http using the MediaPlayer class in android. The ogg stream plays fine on my own device (HTC desire (v2.2.2 with HTC sense)), but many of my users are complaining as i does not work on their devices.

I tried running my app on different android versions (2.1, 2.2, 2.3.3, 4.0.3) using the AVD, where i managed to replicate the error.

Does anybody know what the issue is here? and if so, how can it be mediated?

LogCat output:

```
W/libutils.threads(33): Thread (this=0x151e0): don't call waitForExit() from this Thread object's thread. It's a guaranteed deadlock!
A/VorbisDecoder(33): frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/codecs/vorbis/dec/VorbisDecoder.cpp:251 numPageSamples >= 0
MediaPlayer: error (-100, 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Man, I have so many problems with stream on Android. For me, MediaPlayer doesn't support for stream by http.

The only thing that works to me is the lib Vitamio. Very easy to use, try this: http://vov.io/vitamio/

I repeat, that's the only thing that works to me. I tried buffer while downloading the file, but it is so hard to handle that I gave up.

Comment: I ended up using Vitamio as you recommended, which is fairly ok, except you have to tell your users to go download it.